# Smooth dependence of ODE on zeroth order term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f_s : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth family of functions, and consider the family of ODEs
$$
\dot{x} = f_s(x, t).
$$
Suppose $\varphi_s$ is the unique solution to this ODE satisfying the initial condition $\varphi_s(0) = x_s$, where $x_s \in \mathbb{R}^n$ depends smoothly on $s$. Does the family of solutions depend smoothly on $s$? If so, is there an easy proof of this fact, or where can I find a reference?

Comment: Are you asking whether the map $s\mapsto \varphi_s(t)$ is continuous as a map from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or are you asking whether the map $s\mapsto \varphi_s$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to some Banach space is continuous?

Comment: I am asking if the map $(s, t) \mapsto \varphi_s(t)$ is smooth.

Comment: IIRC Perko and some other texts prove continuous dependence on initial conditions. This post has some more details https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18976/smooth-dependence-of-odes-on-initial-conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. The trick is to reduce the claim to the standard theorem for smooth dependence on initial conditions. Consider the ODE
$$
(\dot{x}, \dot{\sigma}) = (f_\sigma(x, t), 0).
$$
Then for some $s \in \mathbb{R}$, the pair $(x, \sigma) = (\varphi_s, s)$ is the unique solution to the above ODE satisfying the initial condition $(\varphi_s, s)(0) = (x_s, s)$. Then by the smooth dependence of an ODE on its initial conditions, the solutions $(\varphi_s, s)$ depend smoothly on $(x_s, s)$, which implies $\varphi_s$ depends smoothly on $s$.